# Why does Android Wi-Fi not get disabled?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi

I have Android 2.3.4.

I have noticed that even When I turn off Wi-Fi, I still keep getting notifications, like - Gmail, Gtalk and Google+ notifications. If I open the said App then it says that it is not connected to internet.

So, my hypothesis is that maybe when I disable Wi-Fi, Android does not terminate currently established connections. It only denies new connections. But this does not explain why in this case the notifications are usually delayed, sometimes, by few hours or a full day.

What is happening and how do I actually disable the Wi-Fi?

PS: I use the "Status Switch" widget to turn/off the Wi-Fi.

UPDATE: the phone doesn't have a data plan, so data isn't coming in that way.

Comment: Turning off your wifi actually disables the wifi radio hardware, so it can't be that it's maintaining existing connections unless you have an extremely unusual build of Android.

Comment: Hmm.. I am not sure, but it does keeps on sending notifications. More weird is that sometimes I get the notifications after many hours. I have Sony Ericssion Xperia. Maybe it is isolated to Sony phones.

Comment: my best guess currently is that "Status Switch" does not work properly on your phone; check that the Wifi is really disabled through the Settings app.

Comment: Yes there it shows up unchecked.

Comment: Are you sure, your 2G/3G/4G connection is not running? Put a random string in your APN...

Comment: Yes I am sure else I would have got a huge bill.

Answer (score 1):

I belive it is because you gained the data during the period Wi-Fi was activated, so when you swithced off your Wi-Fi, there was still some unread data  you hadn't seen (in the form of mail and G+ notifications). Also I recomed, if you are seriously worried about this, and it perseveres, to turn off Wi-Fi via wireless communications in the settings app.

Comment: All the data, e.g. notifications were generated after I switched off the Wifi from Settings. I seems this is a Sony Ericsson build specific issue (or feature?). I have noticed that even after Wifi is disabled it turns itself on briefly on some seemingly random time.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off Wi-Fi, but you have a data plan with your carrier, you'll still be accessing the internet using your cellular mobile radio.

Opening the app and having it say that it is not connected to the internet could thus be because you have poor signal, or you haven't used your phone in a while and it's been auto-disconnected from the mobile network to save battery/bandwidth by either the phone or your carrier.

You can use Airplane Mode to turn off both cellular and Wi-Fi radios.

Comment: My Data traffic too is disabled. If my phone uses carrier data then that would reflect in my bill. My carrier charges too much for data usage. Also, I have strong network signal.

Comment: You should definitely mention that in your question then.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that.